# Migrate from 2010 to 2019or 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, upgrade-sharepoint

We are looking at moving a site from 2010 to 2016 or 2019. 
Since this is not a supported upgrade path using DB Attach, we are looking at recompiling the WSP'S and deploying them to the new world, and then move the content using Sharegate or something similar. The content does include MySites as well.

Does anyone know if the above approach has worked or should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work, but I would suggest the DB attach method over ShareGate or other third party tools.  Setup a SP2013 single server, attach content DBs to it, then migrate them to 2016, then 2019.  I know it is more work upfront, but you will get a cleaner migration with less issues in the end.

Comment: I went to 2016 from 2010 with DB attach and can vouch for this method being clean.  But the wsp conversion is NOT straight forward and would be easier to redevelop fresh for deployment in 2016 with the same underlying data.  Also don't forget to convert to claims based somewhere in the upgrade process.

Comment: If the WSP solutions were developed without hardcoding or other dirty tricks, generally, SP 2010 WSP are compatible all the way to SP 2019. Don't worry about rebuilding WSP unless you deploy them and detect an issue first.

Comment: @Jammin4CO  thanks. I think by rebuilding you mean recompile the WSP and migrate data similar to what I have in my question.

Comment: No @user3799810 , I mean that the way pages work and webparts are built fundamentally changes with SP13.  You will need to recreate the webpart functionality with the new style.  Recompiling will not suffice in my  experience.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Josh, for upgrade, it is recommended to do DB attach approach and upgrade step by step (2010-2013,2013-2016)  You can test the DB before mount to see if the WSP's have issues.